# How to access another docker volume files with Vue & Laravel?

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-volume

I am running a **Vue & Laravel** project on docker.

[Project structure and everything about the setup](https://medium.com/@crocodile2u/docker-setup-for-a-laravel-vue-project-90e4fd3acc7a)

To start with, I am currently trying to upload images on server.
If I would run this project without docker, it will work as planned *(files are being uploaded on server and they are accessible)*.
However, if I would run this project with docker, it will throw an error *(can't find directory)*.

**Important remark:** I have a guess that it might be happening because I am working with files on the backend (laravel controller, code is down below). So it can access only backend volume.

**It is trying to locate a file at the frontend volume, but it can't access it.**
So, here is the question: **how to access that volume?**

**File controller**:

```
    public function uploadFile (Request $request) {
        # Processing to base64
        $exploded = explode(',', $request->image_data);
        $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);

        # Configuring the extension
        $extension = strtok(explode('/', $exploded[0])[1], ';');

        # Defining the path
        $path = '../../'.'frontend'.'/'.'src'.'/'.'assets'.'/'.'img'.'/'.'files'.'/'.$request->file_name;

        # Uploading file to the storage
        file_put_contents($path, $decoded);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose.yml file? Why are you trying to upload some files inside the vue project? At first glance it seems that the error is that tries to access the `frontend` path that doesn't exist on the laravel project...

Comment: Please avoid adding screenshots of code. People that will try to help you will have to type this code in order to test it. Instead, use code blocks and copy paste your code inside.

Comment: @ChristosLytras look, as I mentioned before, there is nothing wrong with the code in controller. I attached it just for a better vision.

"If I would run this project without docker, it works as planned (files are being uploaded on server).
However, if I would run this project with docker, it would throw an error (can't find directory)."

Comment: @mpccolorado please check out this article: https://medium.com/@crocodile2u/docker-setup-for-a-laravel-vue-project-90e4fd3acc7a. Here you will find the entire setup

Comment: @TyomaInagamov I'm not judging the code, I'm saying that you should not publish code as a screenshot image here and **use code blocks instead**. I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular **"Help others reproduce the problem"** at the third paragraph **"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc"** and also read this Q/A [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @ChristosLytras Thanks for your remarks, every day we learn something new and this day is not an exception. You can check out updates I've made to this question. I hope it got easier for you to understand my problem. Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path here

```
$path = '../../'.'frontend'.'/'.'src'.'/'.'assets'.'/'.'img'.'/'.'files'.'/'.$request->file_name;
```

goes two steps up, then into `frontend` directory. But there is no such directory in your `backend` container.

```yaml
backend:
  volumes:
    - ./backend:/app
    - ./etc/php:/usr/local/etc/php/local.conf.d/
```

These two last lines mount `bakend` and `etc/php` inside the backend container. As you see there is no frontend and so the path you've used on host will not work. Add one more line to fix it:

```yaml
backend:
  volumes:
    - ./backend:/app
    - ./etc/php:/usr/local/etc/php/local.conf.d/
    - ./frontend:/frontend  # this line
```

This will make frontend directory appear at `/frontend` and that should be enough to fix it.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much! God knows how many hours I spent trying to solve this problem. I hope you are doing great and if I would be able to help you in any way I will. Thanks one more time